# Knowing when process ends in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've created a vscode extension where I have this code:

(term is an instance of terminal)

```
term.sendText(cmd, true);
term.processId.then(() => {
    // do something when process starts
});
```

I would know when the process created in terminal ends. I would like to have a reference 'handle' to the process and write `handle.on('end', ()=>{/*do somethig on end*/})`.
Is it possible (also in other way) to run a function when a created process ends?